# Why do official tensorflow models use functions instead of classes?

Tags: python, oop, tensorflow

Models in [tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) (e.g., [`official/resnet`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/resnet/resnet_model.py) and [`research/deeplab`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/model.py)) use functions and passing those parameters & flags repeatedly.

Is there a certain reason for using functions instead of classes (e.g., [YixuanLi/densenet-tensorflow](https://github.com/YixuanLi/densenet-tensorflow/blob/master/cifar10-densenet.py))?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its just for easy understanding, nothing restrict from writing classes.

here is good post on oop implementation

https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/

Comment: Great guideline! Thanks a lot!